# define a two-dimensional global array which its size have to be scanned from a file

Tags: c, data-structures

I want to define a two dimensional array as a global variable:

```
 int visited[nbVertices][nbVertices];
```

but the problem that I have to scan the "nbVertices" from a file. is there anyway to fix this problem ?
 I think it may be fixed by using pointers, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you need a global array? If you could use a local one, then the issue is easy to solve using a VLA.

Comment: it must be global because I have to call it and make changes on it from many functions.

Comment: No, it needn't be global in that case. You can just pass it as an argument to the functions.

Comment: yes you are right, I can pass it as an argument to the function.
I didn't think about it this way.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, while we're at it: you don't need the array to be global. Hence, you can just use variable-length arrays and pass the array to all the functions that need it:

```
void printArray(int n, int k, int arr[n][k])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            printf("%6d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    // get user input in the format "n" <space> "k"
    char *end;
    char buf[LINE_MAX];
    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
        return -1;

    // create array, fill it with random stuff
    int n = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
    int k = strtol(end, NULL, 10);
    int a[n][k];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            a[i][j] = random();
        }
    }

    // print it
    printArray(n, k, a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use malloc.

Your code might look something like this:

```
// somewhere in file, global
int **visited;

// somewhere in your code, when you read nbVertices
visited = malloc(sizeof(int*) * nbVertices);
for(size_t i = 0; i < nbVertices; i++)
    visited[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * nbVertices);
```

there shouldn't be any major differences using `visited`

Comment: I forgot to mention that you will also need to `include <stdlib.h>` for malloc.

Comment: Note that this **will not create a two-dimensional array.** This will create a pointer-to-pointer.